# Unity : is there a way to stop certain scripts when jumping, attacking or performing other actions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i am newbie and beginner in unity
so, i have a 3 script here :

shooting/attacking script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;
    public float cooldownTime = 2f;
    private float nextFireTime = 0f;
    public static int noOfClicks = 0;
    float lastClickedTime = 0;
    float maxComboDelay = 1;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    void Update()
    {

        if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 0.7f && anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("hit1"))
        {
            anim.SetBool("hit1", false);
            noOfClicks = 0;
        }


        if (Time.time - lastClickedTime > maxComboDelay)
        {
            noOfClicks = 0;
        }

        //cooldown time
        if (Time.time > nextFireTime)
        {
            // Check for mouse input
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                OnClick();

            }
        }
    }

    void OnClick()
    {
        lastClickedTime = Time.time;
        noOfClicks++;
        if (noOfClicks == 1)
        {
            anim.SetBool("hit1", true);
        }
        noOfClicks = Mathf.Clamp(noOfClicks, 0, 3);

        if (noOfClicks >= 2 && anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 0.7f && anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("hit1"))
        {
            anim.SetBool("hit1", false);
        }
    }
}
```

and about the bullet :

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ProjectileGunTutorial : MonoBehaviour
{

    //bullet 
    public GameObject bullet;

    //bullet force
    public float shootForce, upwardForce;

    //Gun stats
    public float timeBetweenShooting, spread, reloadTime, timeBetweenShots;
    public int magazineSize, bulletsPerTap;
    public bool allowButtonHold;

    int bulletsLeft, bulletsShot;

    //Recoil
    public Rigidbody playerRb;
    public float recoilForce;

    //bools
    bool shooting, readyToShoot, reloading;

    //Reference
    public Camera fpsCam;
    public Transform attackPoint;

    //Graphics
    public GameObject muzzleFlash;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ammunitionDisplay;

    //bug fixing :D
    public bool allowInvoke = true;

    private void Awake()
    {
        //make sure magazine is full
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        readyToShoot = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        MyInput();

        //Set ammo display, if it exists :D
        if (ammunitionDisplay != null)
            ammunitionDisplay.SetText(bulletsLeft / bulletsPerTap + " / " + magazineSize / bulletsPerTap);
    }
    private void MyInput()
    {
        //Check if allowed to hold down button and take corresponding input
        if (allowButtonHold) shooting = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0);
        else shooting = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0);

        //Reloading 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && bulletsLeft < magazineSize && !reloading) Reload();
        //Reload automatically when trying to shoot without ammo
        if (readyToShoot && shooting && !reloading && bulletsLeft <= 0) Reload();

        //Shooting
        if (readyToShoot && shooting && !reloading && bulletsLeft > 0)
        {
            //Set bullets shot to 0
            bulletsShot = 0;

            Shoot();
        }
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        readyToShoot = false;

        //Find the exact hit position using a raycast
        Ray ray = fpsCam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0)); //Just a ray through the middle of your current view
        RaycastHit hit;

        //check if ray hits something
        Vector3 targetPoint;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            targetPoint = hit.point;
       else
            targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(75); //Just a point far away from the player

        //Calculate direction from attackPoint to targetPoint
        Vector3 directionWithoutSpread = targetPoint - attackPoint.position;

        //Calculate spread
        float x = Random.Range(-spread, spread);
        float y = Random.Range(-spread, spread);

        //Calculate new direction with spread
        Vector3 directionWithSpread = directionWithoutSpread + new Vector3(x, y, 0); //Just add spread to last direction

        //Instantiate bullet/projectile
        GameObject currentBullet = Instantiate(bullet, attackPoint.position, Quaternion.identity); //store instantiated bullet in currentBullet
        //Rotate bullet to shoot direction
        currentBullet.transform.forward = directionWithSpread.normalized;

        //Add forces to bullet
        currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(directionWithSpread.normalized * shootForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(fpsCam.transform.up * upwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        //Instantiate muzzle flash, if you have one
        if (muzzleFlash != null)
            Instantiate(muzzleFlash, attackPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

        bulletsLeft--;
        bulletsShot++;

        //Invoke resetShot function (if not already invoked), with your timeBetweenShooting
        if (allowInvoke)
        {
            Invoke("ResetShot", timeBetweenShooting);
            allowInvoke = false;

            //Add recoil to player (should only be called once)
            playerRb.AddForce(-directionWithSpread.normalized * recoilForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        //if more than one bulletsPerTap make sure to repeat shoot function
        if (bulletsShot < bulletsPerTap && bulletsLeft > 0)
            Invoke("Shoot", timeBetweenShots);
    }
    private void ResetShot()
    {
        //Allow shooting and invoking again
        readyToShoot = true;
        allowInvoke = true;
    }

    private void Reload()
    {
        reloading = true;
        Invoke("ReloadFinished", reloadTime); //Invoke ReloadFinished function with your reloadTime as delay
    }
    private void ReloadFinished()
    {
        //Fill magazine
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        reloading = false;
    }
}
```

and the last is player movement script :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;

    [SerializeField]
    private float gravityMultiplier;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform cameraTransform;

    private Animator animator;
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private float ySpeed;
    private float originalStepOffset;
    private bool isJumping;
    private bool isGrounded;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        originalStepOffset = characterController.stepOffset;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("hit1"))
        {
            return;
        }

        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);
        float magnitude = Mathf.Clamp01(movementDirection.magnitude) * speed;

        movementDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up) * movementDirection;
        movementDirection.Normalize();

        float gravity = Physics.gravity.y * gravityMultiplier;
        ySpeed += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            characterController.stepOffset = originalStepOffset;
            ySpeed = -0.5f;
            animator.SetBool("IsGrounded", true);
            isGrounded = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
            isJumping = false;
            animator.SetBool("IsFalling", false);

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                ySpeed = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3 * gravity);
                animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
                isJumping = true;            }
        }    
        else
        {
            characterController.stepOffset = 0;
            animator.SetBool("IsGrounded", false);
            isGrounded = false;

            if ((isJumping && ySpeed < 0) || ySpeed < -2)
            {
                animator.SetBool("IsFalling", true);
            }
        }

        Vector3 velocity = movementDirection * magnitude;
        velocity = AdjustVelocityToSlope(velocity);
        velocity.y += ySpeed;

        characterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", true);

            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movementDirection, Vector3.up);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 AdjustVelocityToSlope(Vector3 velocity)
    {
        var ray = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 0.2f))
        {var slopeRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
            var adjustedVelocity = slopeRotation * velocity;

            if (adjustedVelocity.y < 0)
            {
                return adjustedVelocity;
            }
        }

        return velocity;
    }
}
```

My character has been able to jump, run, shoot and idle, but when I click the button to shoot while jumping, the bullets come out during a jump animation. it's very strange and unwanted, so is there a way to delay the bullet and shoot when it lands?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of delaying the shoot I suggest just to block it while jumping. You have `isJumping` field in `PlayerMovement` script. You can make a public property for it and check it before shooting, having a SerializedField reference to moving script. So, if you detected a click, you first check if we are jumping now. If so, just return and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation that might help: Time.timeScale = .1f; // just play at 10 times slower than normal speed;

```
float timeScaleDelta = .05f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    ...
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    ...
    float spX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float spY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    // spX, spY Handling up and down

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) // When W is pressed, the bullet time is accelerated
    {
        Time.timeScale += timeScaleDelta;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) // When pressing S, slow down the bullet time to play
    {
        if (Time.timeScale < 0) Time.timeScale = 0;
        else Time.timeScale -= timeScaleDelta;
    }
}
```

If you control the protagonist to jump and fly. Press the S key several times, you can see that the action slows down, and you can clearly see the slow motion.